# UINavigationController 'menu'

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to create a 'book style' interface. I have a plist which holds an array telling me which view controller is the next 'page'. So I check that, push the page onto the stack and fill it with info from the plist.

I also need a 'menu' button though so that users can quickly jump between pages. This is pretty simple but if the users jumps form page 1 to 3 for example and then uses the back button it will obviously pop back to 1. I need it to pop to page 2 though.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I have tried popToViewContorller: animated: but get the error telling me that the vc I'm trying to pop to does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what you need you need to push each page for reaching your desired page means

suppose you want to go 4 page from 1 page then what you need set a integer variable(make it property in app delegate class) according to you view number.
then push next view according to your plist then check this your desired page (by checking your page number save in property and current page number). if yes then remains there otherwise push other one.(this will done viewDidLoad of each page).

Remember when you got your desired page then set that bool variable to NO;

For managing page number add one more thing in plist thats page number with that and then make your logic.

Comment: I am trying your method but keep getting the error: "Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist". I show view 1, push view 2, and then get the error when I try to pop back to view 1.

Comment: Is this because when I try to put I init/alloc a new instance of the view I want to pop too? Should I be creating all the views before in my app delegate?

Comment: Ok, problem solved. I needed to create all the view controllers in the app delegate and pop to those references. Thanks.

Comment: sorry for late reply but now you got solution with your clean dedication so cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think u can do it by poppingViewControcollers.Its that in ur navigationController.viewControllers array u will just have page1 at zero index & page3 at 1 index.When u do  popToViewContorller: animated: its takes you to just immediate previous navigationController viewController that its being loaded like in ur case its page 1 is loaded before page3.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that's the problem. How do I get page 2 to load in the middle so that I can pop back to it? Is there a way that I can tell the navigationcontroller all of its view controllers in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is not a `UINavigationController` at all? It is designed to manage a stack of view controllers, but what you want is a list of controllers.

You can make your own custom subclass of `UIViewController` that manages an array of sub view controllers, populating a `UIScrollView` with the views from the managed view controllers.

This way the `UIScrollView` can:

- Handle paging for you
- Back, forward and even jump is simply a matter of setting the `contentOffset`.

You say you have all the view controller in a plist, so they can not be too many. So no need to worry about dynamic creation and complex life-cycle management of the managed view controllers.